# Format a PHP array to JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Is it possible to make this, from a PHP array, to a JSON array? If so, could someone explain a little further?

```
events: [
    {
        title: 'Test event',
        location: 'Test location',
        start: {
            date: '20140607', time: '17.00'
        },
        end: {
            date: '20140623', time: '17.00'
        }
    },
    {
        title: 'Test event',
        location: 'Test location',
        start: {
            date: '20140607', time: '17.00'
        },
        end: {
            date: '20140623', time: '17.00'
        }
    }
],
```

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
   $json->title = 'Test event';
   $json->location  = 'Test location';

   echo json_encode($json);
?>

{"title":"Test event","location":"Test location"}
```

Comment: ? this question is very vague and you already got what you wanted ?

Comment: Is there something wrong with your JSON when you use `json_encode()`?

Comment: I think he wants a pretty formatting function.

Comment: Sorry! How would I do the start { }, end {} areas, and make it into an array?

Comment: Just build an array of objects in php and then encode it.

Comment: ^^ This is what I am having an issue with. I can work out how to build an array of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track but to go further you have to make it multidimensional (You can write it as an object but I prefer arrays):

```
<?php
$jsonArr['title'] = 'Test event';
$jsonArr['location']  = 'Test location';

$jsonArr['start']['date']= '20140607';
$jsonArr['start']['time']= '17.00';

$jsonArr['end']['date']= '20140607';
$jsonArr['end']['time']= '17.00';

echo json_encode($jsonArr);

//Or an object example:

$json->title = 'Test event';
$json->location  = 'Test location';

$json->start->date= '20140607';
$json->start->time= '17.00';

$json->end->date= '20140607';
$json->end->time= '17.00';

echo json_encode($json);

?>

{"title":"Test event","location":"Test location","start":{"date":"20140607","time":"17.00"},"end":{"date":"20140607","time":"17.00"}}
```

That should do you fine

Comment: I meant to ask, what about multiple events? And could you show an object example? Just trying to get my head around it.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple events? I will edit an object example in

Comment: Thank you! So, if I was to include this in a JS script function, would this be the best way to do it? http://snippi.com/s/8z9wq4t

Comment: That is the best way as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` option of [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
<?php
   $json = new stdClass();
   $json->title = 'Test event';
   $json->location  = 'Test location';

   echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

**Edit:**

> How would I do the start { }, end {} areas, and make it into an array?

You can define the variable like this:

```
$json = array(
  'events' => array(
    array(
      'title' => 'Test event',
      'location' => 'Test location',
      'start' => array(
        'date' => '20140607',
        'time' => '17.00'
      ),
      'end' => array(
        'date' => '20140623',
        'time' => '17.00'
      )
    ),
    array(
      'title' => 'Test event',
      'location' => 'Test location',
      'start' => array(
        'date' => '20140607',
        'time' => '17.00'
      ),
      'end' => array(
        'date' => '20140623',
        'time' => '17.00'
      )
    )
  )
);
```

It outputs:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "title": "Test event",
            "location": "Test location",
            "start": {
                "date": "20140607",
                "time": "17.00"
            },
            "end": {
                "date": "20140623",
                "time": "17.00"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Test event",
            "location": "Test location",
            "start": {
                "date": "20140607",
                "time": "17.00"
            },
            "end": {
                "date": "20140623",
                "time": "17.00"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So, if I was to include this in a JS script function, would this be the best way to do it? http://snippi.com/s/8z9wq4t

Comment: If the events come from the database, then yes. But if data is static (included in the source file), then you can do it without PHP. In that case just use JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/r2nAe/1/

Answer (score 0):

Json_encode also works on arrays:

From the manual (http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Ideone: http://ideone.com/rD2Yvg

**EDIT:**
As pointed out earlier, you may be looking for formatting options:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Especially: JSON_PRETTY_PRINT